# How do I read a single String from standard input?

Tags: string, rust, stdin

There isn't straightforward instruction on receiving a string as a variable in the [std::io documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0-alpha/std/io/index.html), but I figured this should work:

```
use std::io;
let line = io::stdin().lock().lines().unwrap();
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
src\main.rs:28:14: 28:23 error: unresolved name `io::stdin`
src\main.rs:28          let line = io::stdin.lock().lines().unwrap();
                                   ^~~~~~~~~
```

Why?

I'm using a nightly Rust v1.0.

Comment: Have you read [The Rust Book's section on standard input](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/standard-input.html)?

Comment: @Shepmaster Yes, but I figured 'old_io' means it's a deprecated feature. Is it other way around?

Comment: The documentation you are referring to is for the first alpha release. The module then called `io` was renamed `old_io` *after* that release, and it is indeed on the way out, but not yet completely superseded by the new `io` module. First you need to figure out where you stand: Are you using 1.0.0-alpha or are you tracking nightlies?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's the code you need to do what you are trying (no comments on if it is a good way to go about it:

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let line = stdin.lock()
        .lines()
        .next()
        .expect("there was no next line")
        .expect("the line could not be read");
}
```

If you want more control over where the line is read to, you can use [`Stdin::read_line`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.read_line). This accepts a `&mut String` to append to. With this, you can ensure that the string has a large enough buffer, or append to an existing string:

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn main() {
    let mut line = String::new();
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    stdin.lock().read_line(&mut line).expect("Could not read line");
    println!("{}", line)
}
```

Comment: in the `read_line()` example, wouldn't it be more appropriate to use `.ok().expect()` pattern for the return value? You're not doing anything with the `unwrap()`ped value.

Comment: @tilde I don't know about *more* appropriate, but I don't think it would be *less* appropriate either. When you `unwrap` a `Result`, the error value will be used as the panic message. With your example, you'd need to provide an error message for `expect`, which might be more appropriate for your use case.

Comment: I didn't think about the fact that the error value would be propagated to the panic anyways, thanks for the clarification!